# Запятая при неоднородных сказуемых

Tags: сказуемые, пунктуация

Нужно ли ставить запятую при неоднородных сказуемых, если они:

1. Оба выражены глаголом, но в разной форме.

Например, "Я всю жизнь любил ее(,) и до сих пор питаю к ней уважение".
Одно сказуемое несовершенного вида в прошедшем времени, другое - в настоящем.

1. Они выражены разными частями речи.

Он очень красив(,) и всегда понимал это.

Одно сказуемое выражено кратким прилагательным, другое - глаголом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом примере не нужна, во втором – факультативна. Если вторую основу считать неполной... но это немножко за уши притянуто. Скорее всего и здесь не нужна.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь можно говорить только о морфологической неоднородности сказуемых, и запятая ставится в обоих предложениях. С точки зрения грамматики, эти сказуемые  являются однородными.

Для сравнения: "Оставив нарты на некотором расстоянии, охотники осторожно приближались к туше и вдруг остановились изумленные".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

По поводу предложений с несколькими сказуемыми в лингвистике нет однозначного решения. Одни из них можно считать простыми предложениями с однородными сказуемыми, другие считаются промежуточными структурами между простым и сложным предложением.

При наличие союза И предложение с несколькими  сказуемыми обычно считается простым (запятая при наличии двух сказуемых не ставится).

На другой вариант может указывать  коммуникативная расчлененность и самостоятельность частей предложения, например: "Он приобрел свой прежний человеческий облик, но (он) был чрезвычайно мрачен и даже, пожалуй, раздражен". Это тот случай, который можно отнести к промежуточной структуре.