# Почему запятая перед "и утомили" стоит?

Tags: пунктуация

> Все эти мотивы повторяются из года в год, и утомили меня бесконечно.

Почему здесь запятая перед "и утомили"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Веллер:

> Хорошее знание грамматики в сочетании с логикой позволяет
> поднаторевшему автору доказать формальную правильность любого строя
> предложения, любого синтаксиса. Скажем, однородные члены предложения
> при наличии союза «и» запятыми не разделяются: «Я пришел и сел».
> Напишем: «Я пришел, и сел». На первый взгляд, элементарная ошибка. Но
> предположим, что автору зачем-то понадобилось написать так. Тогда
> «сел» можно рассматривать как отдельное предложение,
> нераспространенное и неполное, где есть лишь сказуемое «сел» и
> опущено, подразумевается существительное «я»: «Я пришел, и (я) сел».
> Таким образом, имеем вместо одного предложения с двумя однородными
> сказуемыми – два простых предложения, образующих сложносочиненное
> предложение с союзом «и», а такой случай требует запятой. Формализм?
> Отчаянный. Но только так можно защитить свое авторское право на отход
> от усредненного канона, на индивидуальный стиль с элементами
> выверенного аграмматизма.

(Лично я такой подход не разделяю, лишь демонстрирую, что формально запятую в приведённом вами предложении можно оправдать.)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133791/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid------).

Answer (score 1):

Когда человек изначально не задумывал предложение с двумя однородными, но по ходу произношения решает дополнить его однородным и делает это после короткой паузы, то это будет присоединение, присоединительная интонация и причина ставить запятую в такой ситуации. В справочнике Розенталя есть пункт об этом, вот он:

> Если союз и имеет присоединительное значение (с помощью этого союза может присоединяться также неоднородный член предложения), то перед ним ставится запятая: [Лизавета Ивановна] разливала чай, и получала выговоры за лишний расход сахара; она вслух читала романы, и виновата была во всех ошибках автора; она сопровождала графиню в её прогулках, и отвечала за погоду и за мостовую (П.).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! К сожалению, нет возможности принять ответ два раза :)

Comment: Конечно, вы не можете принять два ответа. Но — Вы можете хотя бы оценить второй, поставив плюсик ("ответ полезен"). Странно, что Вы этого не сделали.

Answer (score 1):

*К стыду своему, в первой версии ответа не заметил самого главного. ответ переделал.*

**Запятая возможна в силу неоднородности сказуемых**. Они имеют разную видо-временную категорию: первое - НСВ, второе - СВ. Это не является абсолютным и достаточным признаком неоднородности, но дает веские основания считать именно так. Кое-что по этому поводу - тут: [Запятая при неоднородных сказуемых](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/37604)

(+)----

Насчет мнения Веллера.
Надо сказать, что Веллер тут не оригинален - подобные идеи и обсуждения велись задолго
появления его ["технологии рассказа"](https://readli.net/chitat-online/?b=48694&pg=1), откуда и взята цитата).

> Скажем, однородные члены предложения при наличии союза «и» запятыми не
> разделяются: «Я пришел и сел».

Именно так. Все остальное - от лукавого. У Веллера (коего я вполне уважаю как автора) - обыкновенная спекуляция на тему [грамматической омонимии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%8F). Тут дело вот в чем. До появления компьютерных технологий никто не ставил себе целью исследовать грамматику фразы на однозначность - в этом просто не было необходимости. Сейчас же "по умолчанию" исповедуется следующий подход. Грамматику можно трактовать по-разному тогда и только тогда, когда это влечет за собой различия в семантике, то есть когда существует реальная семантическая неоднозначность. Иначе выбирается более простая из двух (или более) возможностей грамматического разбора.
Конкретно, есть ли какое-либо смысловое различие во фразах "я пришел и сел" и "я пришел, и сел"? Такое различие в принципе невозможно рассмотреть. А следовательно, из двух возможных трактовок грамматики следует принимать наиболее простую (то есть - с однородными сказуемыми), и соответственно этому использовать и правила пунктуации.

> позволяет поднаторевшему автору доказать формальную правильность
> любого строя предложения,

Мне кажется, Веллер злоупотребляет доверием читателя.
Хочется спросить, а кому "поднаторевший" взялся ***доказывать*** ?
Ни один корректор не будет заморачиваться подобными "доказательствами"- в лучшем случае он просто воспользуется принципом "автор всегда прав" - такой принцип действительно существует, применяется тогда и только тогда, когда корректор исчерпал все возможности доказать автору его неправоту. А вот редактор, если заметит подобное, скорее всего, уже не пропустит - и никакие доказательства не помогут.

(+) ====

> Если союз и имеет присоединительное значение (с помощью этого союза
> может присоединяться также неоднородный член предложения), то перед
> ним ставится запятая:

(Розенталь)
(из цитаты в ответе @JimKorbett)

Пример к месту, согласен. Но нуждается в пояснениях.
Мне трудно спорить с Розеталем предметно - да и нет в том необходимости.
Я бы просто уточнил формулировку. Такая пунктуация возможна, если два члена (сказуемых в данном случае) могут по задумке автора восприниматься как неоднородные. Само понятие однородности-неоднородности не формализовано, поэтому естественно могут быть разночтения, но в целом подход понятен. В примере Розенталя из Пушкина о такой неоднородности свидетельствует разная роль героини (подлежащего) - разливала чай (активна) и получала выговоры (пассивна). Фактически даже последнюю часть ("сопровождала" и "отвечала") можно трактовать как противопоставление активной и пассивной роли Лизаньки,  хотя на это уже - воля автора, без контекста такую неоднородность можно и не усмотреть.